# Get Display name for group users for multiple groups, from a filtered list of groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

*Bear with me on my first question on any online forum ever.* =]

My intent is to use PowerShell to create a csv with the following information:

- Group Name *(only print groups whose name match text string "O365*")*
- What users are a member of this group.
- What are the user emails for each of these members

Currently, My script is as follows.

```
    Get-ADGroup -filter {name -like "O365*"} -properties GroupCategory | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty name | 
    get-adgroupmember | 
    where {$_.objectclass -eq 'user'} |
    Get-ADUSer -properties Displayname,Description,Mail |
    Select Name,Displayname,Mail
```

This result provides me with:

- 1 column for Displayname
- 1 column for Mail

I feel as though I have missed the answer time and time again after researching this for a while. Most people seem content to do this similar task without filtering the ADGroup cmdlet, but that would take too long for me.

As a newbie, I am excited to hear from anyone who'll take the time to answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the users that are the member of a group with a name matching "O365* And they need to be displayed as

```
Group.Name | User.DisplayName | User.Mail
```

Simply looking at the question one could think the following code would do the trick and it works but there is a catch ......

```
cls
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"
#$VerbosePreference = "Continue"
#$DebugPreference = "Continue"

Write-Verbose "Retrieving the ADGroups"
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -filter {name -like "O365*"}  
Write-Debug  ($Groups | Select Name | Format-Table | Out-String)

$UserList = @()   

Foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    Write-Verbose "Processing Group $Group"
    $GroupMembers = $Group | Get-ADGroupMember
    Write-Debug  "GroupMembers:  $($GroupMembers | Select Name | Format-Table | Out-String)"

    Foreach ($GroupMember in $GroupMembers) {
        Write-Verbose "Processing GroupMember $GroupMember"
        Write-Debug  "GroupMember $($GroupMember | Out-String)"

        if (!($GroupMember.objectClass -eq "user")) {

            Write-Warning "GroupMember $($GroupMember) is not of type 'User', Skipping"
            Continue

        }

        else {

            Try {
                $UserList += ($GroupMember | Get-ADUSer -properties Mail | Select @{N="Group"; E={$Group.Name}}, Name, Mail)
                Write-Verbose "user $GroupMember has been added to the list."
            }

            Catch {
                Write-Warning "An error ocurd while adding user $GroupMember to the list."
                Continue
            }

        }
    }
}

$UserList
```

If the o365 groups contain other groups then the members of these subgroups will not be included.

Output Example

```
WARNING: GroupMember CN=subgroup,OU=Custom,DC=DOMAIN,DC=TLD is not of type 'User', Skipping

Group                                       Name                                       Mail                                      
-----                                       ----                                       ----                                      
o365-SubscriptionA                          User U. UserLand                           User@Domain.tld                           
o365-SubscriptionA                          User2 U2. UserLand                         User2@Domain.tld                          
o365-SubscriptionB                          User U. UserLand                           User@Domain.tld
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right on track with my inquiry.

I am certain that these groups "O365*" only contain individual users, and do not have groups within them.

I will try what is here and see if I can obtain the desired result.

Thanks again.

Comment: @DrewStevens code updated, i even added some extra things, it still needs some more love but that is for you.

Comment: Wow! you rock! Thank you very much. I am looking forward to learning more. Thanks for a great first experience.